# python docker sdk; get information about dangling docker images

Tags: python, docker

I have been trying for a while to get images information trying to follow the docs:
[This doc specifically](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html)

> #### list(**kwargs)
>
> List images on the server.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - **name** (*str*) -- Only show images belonging to the repository `name`
> - **all** (*bool*) -- Show intermediate image layers. By default, these are filtered out.
> - **filters** (*dict*) -- Filters to be processed on the image list. Available filters: - `dangling` (bool) - `label` (str): format either `key` or `key=value`

Now when I try and I have tried many things I can not figure out the right syntax:

```
sh-4.2# python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct 30 2018, 23:45:53)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import docker
>>> client = docker.from_env()
>>> for image in client.images.list('dangling'):
...     print image.id
...
>>> for image in client.images.list('dangling=true'):
...     print image.id
...
>>>
```

I have also tried other stuff, but just can't figure out how it works.
What I need to is essentially filter them by dangling or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the explanation above it say it requires a dict: `filters (dict)`

In addition, the tutorial example at https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guides/swarm_services.html#listing-services provides a dict for filters, albeit for services it should hold true for images too.

As such please try:

`client.images.list(filters={'dangling': True})`